# Counting number of "passes" within a loop

Tags: list, loops, csv, python-3.x, import

Here's my code, in a nutshell it imports data from a csv file, reads it and determines pupils percentages and grades from their two marks stored in the csv file. What I'm trying to do is find and store how many A,B,C,D grades and fails there are, then output them at the end in a way like "There was 2 A passes" "There was 4 B passes" and so on....

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
import csv

with open ("UASHSDDP3efiles.csv", "r") as csvfile: #Reads the csv file and puts the names into a list
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    list0 = []
    for row in reader:
        list0.append(row[0])

with open ("UASHSDDP3efiles.csv", "r") as csvfile: #Reads the csv file and puts the prelim marks into a list
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    list1 = []
    for row in reader:
        list1.append(row[1])

with open ("UASHSDDP3efiles.csv", "r") as csvfile: #Reads the csv file and puts the coursework marks into a list
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    list2 = []
    for row in reader:
        list2.append(row[2])

list3 = [(int(x) + int(y)) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)] #Creates a list with each set of marks added together

for i in range(len(list3)): #Creates a loop to go through the list
    totalmark = list3[i] #Takes the first piece of data and calls it totalmarks, on the second loop, it will be the second piece of data and so on...
    percentage = (totalmark / 150) * 100 #Finds the percentage of their total mark out of 150

    if percentage >=  70: #Checks if they have received an A grade
        grade = "A"
    if 60 <= percentage < 70: #Checks if they have received a B grade
        grade = "B"
    if 50 <= percentage < 60: #Checks if they have received a C grade
        grade = "C"
    if 45 <= percentage < 50: #Checks if they have received a D grade
        grade = "D" 
    if percentage < 45: #Checks if they haven't received a grade
        grade = "No grade"

    roundedpercentage = round(percentage) #Rounds the percentage to the nearest integer
    print(list0[i],"'s percentage was", roundedpercentage,"%", "and their grade was:", grade) #Prints the pupils name, percentage and grade

max=max(list3) #Finds the highest mark
print("The highest mark achieved was:", max)
min=min(list3) #Finds the lowest mark
print("The lowest mark achieved was:", min)
```

**And here's the output:**

```
>>> Alison Brown 's percentage was 71 % and their grade was: A
Peter Smith 's percentage was 41 % and their grade was: No grade
Katrina Cunningham 's percentage was 60 % and their grade was: B
Jason Talbot 's percentage was 40 % and their grade was: No grade
Shahida Choudry 's percentage was 70 % and their grade was: A
Ian Li 's percentage was 50 % and their grade was: C
Petra Carter 's percentage was 39 % and their grade was: No grade
Hermann Zimmer 's percentage was 69 % and their grade was: B
Tatiana Krystof 's percentage was 60 % and their grade was: B
Oliver Hirschbiegal 's percentage was 49 % and their grade was: D
Lola Portillo 's percentage was 59 % and their grade was: C
Alberto Maura 's percentage was 69 % and their grade was: B
Diana Elliot 's percentage was 25 % and their grade was: No grade
Hilary Clark 's percentage was 49 % and their grade was: D
Ruksana Cabuk 's percentage was 11 % and their grade was: No grade
The highest mark achieved was: 106
The lowest mark achieved was: 17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dict with grades as keys, and increment values for each grade encountered. The for loop becomes *(made a few code simplifications for readability)*:

```
# create the dict first
gradescount = dict()

for student, totalmark in zip(list0, list3): # iterate directly over the lists
    percentage = (totalmark / 150) * 100
    if percentage >= 70:
        grade = "A"
    elif percentage >= 60:  #elif prevents extra tests
        grade = "B"
    elif percentage >= 50:
        grade = "C"
    elif percentage >= 45:
        grade = "D"
    else:
        grade = "No grade"

    # Increment appropriate grade counter
    gradescount[grade] = gradescount.get(grade, 0) + 1

    roundedpercentage = round(percentage)
    print("%s's percentage was %d%% and their grade was: %s" % (
            student,
            roundedpercentage,
            grade
    ))
```

Then, at the end of your script:

```
for grade in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'):
    print("There were %d %s passes" % (gradescount.get(grade, 0), grade))
print("There were %d fails" % (gradescount.get('No grade', 0),))
```

In the hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

make an array of five elements a=np.zeros(5). in each grade make code

`if percentage >= 70:
        grade = "A"
        ind=ord(grade)-ord("A")
        a[ind]=a[ind]+1`
in cae of else i.e. no grade 
make `a[4]=a[4]+1`. and you will get an array with desired answer